# Using Jasper str Function From External Java Code

Tags: java, jasper-reports, resourcebundle

I have a Jasper report that retrieves a CLOB field that contains XML data with key-value pairs, I wrote a class that reads the CLOB, parse the XML and return a MAP contains the key-value pairs. Is there a way to parse the map in iReport with the ability to apply Jasper functions to it (e.g `str(...)`)?

To clarify things, the keys are keys for the resource file that is attached to the report, that's why I need the `str` function for example.

I tried to return it as a single string instead of a map, containing `$R{KEY}` or `str(KEY)`, but no luck, they are both parsed as a string.

Any idea or workaround?

EDIT 1:
The retrieved map size is unknown, it might contain one key-value entry or ten key-value entries, depending on what is stored in the database. Also, keys are important, I need their value in the resource file. See below a sample:

Resource file:

```
key1 = Brand
key2 = Price
key3 = Location
...
```

The retrieved map for row 1 from the database is:

```
key1: BMW
key2: 20000
key3: Germany
```

The retrieved map for row 2 from the database is:

```
key1: Audi
key2: 30000
```

The output in the report for the needed field should be:

```
row 1:
Brand BMW
Price 20000
Location Germany

row2:
Brand Audi
Price 30000
```

EDIT 2:
I was able to do something close of what I want, but in a nasty way in my opinion, what I did is that I wrote a class to take the CLOB and return a map with key-value pairs, and I did the following in the jrxml:
- A variable `MAP` that holds this map, having the expression `path.to.class.getMap($F{CLOB_DATA})`
- A variable `KEY_IT` that holds an iterator to be used for keys `$V{MAP}.entrySet().iterator()`
- A variable `VAL_IT` that holds an iterator to be used for values `$V{MAP}.entrySet().iterator()`

Now, I can use those iterators like this:

```
row 1, cell 1:
$V{KEY_IT}.hasNext() ? str((String)((Map.Entry)$V{KEY_IT}.next()).getKey()) : ""

row 2, cell 1:
$V{KEY_IT}.hasNext() ? str((String)((Map.Entry)$V{KEY_IT}.next()).getKey()) : ""

.
.
.

row 1, cell 2:
$V{VAL_IT}.hasNext() ? (String)((Map.Entry)$V{VAL_IT}.next()).getValue() : ""

row 2, cell 2:
$V{VAL_IT}.hasNext() ? (String)((Map.Entry)$V{VAL_IT}.next()).getValue() : ""

.
.
.
```

But, I had to put so many cells under each other containing the same expression, so this is the worst part, if I have one entry or 20 entries, the report will be the same height, also, there is a maximum for the entries as I have to put them specifically in a text field and give them the expression, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can't understand where your problem is?, you like to elaborate it in java before passing datasrouce to report?, you like to elaborate inside of the jrxml?, can you show some short jrxml?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I will post a sample of my jrxml. My problem is that I have a CLOB value from the database, it contains an XML that has key-value pairs that I don't how many are they, is there a way to loop through them in the jrxml file? Having in mind that all keys themself are keys in the resource bundle that is included in the jrxml file. Please check my edit too.